# WPF TabItem style when mouse left button is down

Tags: wpf, tabitem, multitrigger

I am defining a Style for WPF `TabControl` `TabItem`.
I want to show a slight "pushed down" effect on `TabItem` when mouse (left button) is pressed down and the `TabItem` is not selected but I cannot find the `Trigger` for this.

I have tried to define a `MultiTrigger` with `IsMouseLeftButtonDown` and `IsPressed` properties but neither one is recognized.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
      <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                  <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                        <Border Name="bd" BorderThickness="1,1,0,0">
                            <Grid>
                                <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                  ContentSource="Header"/>    
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsMouseLeftButtonDown" Value="True" /> <!--NOT RECOGNIZED-->
                                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False" />
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter TargetName="bd" Property="Background" >
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                         <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                              <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="0"/>
                                              <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="1"/>
                                         </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                 </Setter>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                       </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                 </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
       </Setter>
 </Style>
```

**How to set a `Trigger` that gets into action when mouse left button is pressed down on a `TabItem` ?**

---

EDIT

I tried `EventTrigger` but I don't see any effect with the below

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
     <BeginStoryboard>
           <Storyboard>
               <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Green" Duration="0:0:3" />
           </Storyboard>
     <BeginStoryboard/>
<EventTrigger/>
```

Can it be achieved with this way somehow ?

Comment: This will not work. If you want to listen on a MouseAction, you have to use `EventTrigger`. Eventriggers only will accept one Condition. Therefore your `IsSelected=False` wont work. A Workaround might be, using  `IsMouseOver` instead of `IsMouseLeftButtonDown`. That will simulate a Hover-Effect

Comment: IsMouseOver is incorrect here since it gives you a hover effect. I have that implemented already correctly.

Comment: Edited the post for EventTrigger but can't get it work

Answer (score 0):

This example shows you, how to work with `EventTriggers`.

**Note**

You might have to set your Highlighting-Logic fully in those `Triggers`, since values are overridden everytime, the `Trigger` fires.

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="PreviewMouseDown" >
    <EventTrigger.Actions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard >
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="bd" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background"  Duration="0:0:3" BeginTime="0" AutoReverse="True">
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame  KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{x:Static Brushes.Green}" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger.Actions>
</EventTrigger>
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="PreviewMouseUp" >
    <EventTrigger.Actions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard >
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="bd" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background"  Duration="0:0:3" BeginTime="0" AutoReverse="True">
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame  KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{x:Static Brushes.Transparent}" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger.Actions>
</EventTrigger>
```